# C++ how to use CreateProcess to get handle on process?

Tags: c++, window, exe, handle, createprocess

I am trying to open a exe from a known path. Then once the exe is fully loaded get the window handle. I know this can be done all from CreateProcess I am just not sure how.

The program is very large so I need to make sure I only get the handle once it is fully loaded.

Thank You.

Comment: CreateProcess does not return window handles. You'll need WaitForInputIdle and then FindWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From David Heffernan

> CreateProcess does not return window handles. You'll need
>   WaitForInputIdle and then FindWindow.

Thank you!